# Favorite Questions and Answers from third quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, blog

### This post has been [published](https://thesffblog.com/2017/10/highlights-from-2017-3rd-quarter/).

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from July 1st 2017 through September 30 2017 (**They don't have to be *your* questions and answers, but it also doesn't matter if you want to self promote your own stuff.**).

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/07/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

### Votes

People sometimes down-vote the answers, even going as far as to target specific people and vote them into the negative. Just so you know, that is a pointless practice. All answers are included regardless of vote count (unless I decide not to include one for some reason). Also the vote score does not determine the order in which things will appear in the post, I tend to arbitrarily do that when I write it up.

Blah blah blah. I am not a duplicate of another question (even though I very nearly am)!

Comment: Strange, you didn't feature DCop's answer in the blog post... Is that normal?

Comment: @Möoz His answer came after I had already posted the blog.

Answer (score 7):

Traditionally, I have tried to post a short list of interesting or exceptional questions / answers of other users here that have caught my eye, but I haven't been involved enough this quarter to have made such a list.

Breaking with tradition and taking a cue from Valorum's end-of-quarter lists, I thought I might offer a question of my own. I posted this one on the very first day of the quarter **in honour of Canada Day**, which was a bigger celebration than usual this year given that it was Canada's 150th birthday:

- [**Is the Klingon Bird of Prey a Canada Goose?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162655/)

I found **@Vanguard3000**'s answer, which unearthed some Star Trek design facts that I didn't know, to be very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

### **Favorite Question(s)**

I have two questions to promote this quarter. The first one is

> [What kind of creature is Pac-Man?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167201/75000)

and the second

> [Why is Sonic so fast?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/168839/75000)

The questions themselves are simple but made me realize that I was missing out on two very important origin stories, and that I needed them in my life (badly).

### **Favorite Answer(s)**

Obviously the answers to my favorite questions have to make an appearance this time.

> @CreationEdge went to amazing depths to find out about [Pac-Man's species](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/167234/75000), and @Valorum's answer about [Sonic's speed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/168845/75000) surprised the heck out of me

I'd also like to give a shoutout to @TheDarkLord for their [great answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/169062/75000) on my question of [why Hermione was always late when she used the Time Turner](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/169057/75000). The comparisons between the books are the movies are especially breathtaking.

### **Honorable Mention**

The question of

> [Why are kicks so effective in a lightsaber duel?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/164266/75000)

made me laugh. Normally the question might be ridiculous, but because it's set inside the mess that is the Star Wars universe it makes perfect sense and allowed me to have more of an appreciation for the prequels.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! +1. "Me too"

Comment: @Möoz No, thank you!